# jquery .data(): is it portable to all the browser?

Tags: jquery

I just want to use it, it's good thing but I am not sure if it's supported by all major browsers.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/data/ says that it doesn't work on XML on IE. Does it mean that it will work with HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am not sure if it's supported by all major browsers.

It is. jQuery brings its own data storage implementation that is independent from browsers.

Additionally, HTML 5's `data-*` properties get pulled in when present (i.e. they are accessible through `.data()`).

According to the manual, the only exception is XML documents:

> Note that this method currently does not provide cross-platform support for setting data on XML documents, as Internet Explorer does not allow data to be attached via expando properties.

[jQuery docs on .data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: +1, thanks for the insight on html5 and jquery's handling of `data-` attributes.. very interesting